# Dividing the linear congruence equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

$$42x \equiv 12 \pmod {90}$$

This is a pretty simple congruence equation. $\gcd(42,90)=6$; $6|12 \implies $ a solutions exists.

I've always been solving congruence equations with that scheme:

$$\gcd(42,90)=1*90-2*42$$

$$90k + \frac{-2*12}{6}=90k-4$$

This should be the solution. It satisfies the equation too, so everything is ok.

However, according to [this](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra_2ed/guide/soln13.pdf) pdf, the soulutions are also $11$, $26$, $41$,... They divided the equation by $6$. I however don't like the way they did it. I've always seen people doing this with the following results:

$$7x \equiv 2 \pmod {90}$$

without dividing the $\pmod {90}$ part. So should I divide it as well, or not? That's pretty confusing.

---

If the answer is positive, and the simplified equation is correct, then are all its solutions correct for the top equation in this thread? I mean, this equation has $\pmod {90}$, the other $\pmod {15}$, I don't see how they can be equal.

Comment: If you divide a congruence $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ by $k$, where $k$ divides $a$ and $b$, you must divide the modulus $m$ by $\gcd(m,k)$. Here, you get $7x\equiv 2 \pmod{15}$.

Comment: So if I have $17x \equiv 1 (mod 5)$, and I want to get rid of the variable coefficient, I get $x \equiv 17^{-1} (mod \frac{5}{17})$?

Comment: No. Since $\gcd(17,5) = 1$, you divide the modulus by $1$, that is, leave it unchanged. If you divide $12x \equiv 8 \pmod{30}$ by $4$, for example, you must divide the modulus $30$ by $\gcd(30,4) = 2$.

Comment: Oh, right, ok, I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Consider the congruence 
$$ax\equiv ay \pmod{n}.\tag{1}$$

If $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then the congruence (1) is equivalent to the congruence $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$.

More generally, if $\gcd(a,n)=d$, then the congruence (1) is equivalent to the congruence $x\equiv y \pmod{\frac{n}{d}}$. If we put $d=1$, we arrive at the special case dealt with in the preceding paragraph.

For your particular numbers, the original congruence is equivalent to $7x\equiv 2\pmod{15}$. This has the solution $x\equiv 11\pmod{15}$. This solution is unique **modulo** $15$.

If we want to express the answers modulo the original $90$, there are **several** solutions. For $x\equiv 11\pmod{15}$ if and only if $x$ is congruent to one of $11,26,41,56,71,86$ modulo $90$. (We keep adding $15$'s.)

Comment: a very complete answer André +1