# Congruence system with same modulus and same variable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have this particular problem:
$$\begin{cases}
3k \equiv 2 \pmod 8 \dots(*) \\
7k \equiv 2 \pmod 8 \dots(**)
\end{cases}
$$

I know that the solution for this is $k = 8q + 6$. I can find this easily if I solve one of the equations alone.

Now, let's assume I subtract $(*)$ from $(**)$. I get $4k\equiv0[8]$ and $k = 2q$, which isn't coherent.

For example, if I take $q = 2$ then $3k=12$, which does not satisfy $(*)$ (nor $(**)$).

I can't figure out where I messed up. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Where did $k = 2q$ come from?

Comment: @BrianYao $4k\equiv0 \pmod 8$ which means $4k = 8q$.

Comment: You don't know what $q$ is.  $q$ could be any integer.  And $q$ is *irrelevant* to congruencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mess up anywhere, except for your interpretation of what you did. The result that $k=2q'$ (I'm using a different letter to avoid confusion with the $q$ from $k=8q+6$) is correct — the solutions $k=8q+6$ indeed satisfy this property that you found:
$$k=8q+6=2q', \quad \text{where} \quad q'=4q+3.$$

When you have two equations to begin with, and you combine them e.g. by subtracting, what you get is an *implication* but **NOT** an *equivalent* equation. In other words:

- each $k$ that satisfies the original system of equations also satisfies the new equation;
- but values of $k$ that satisfy the new equation do not have to satisfy the original system.

As an example, think of the usual system of equations that I'm sure you've seen before; say, something like:
$$\begin{cases} 2x+3y=11, \\ 3x+4y=12. \end{cases}$$

When you subtract the first equation from the second, you'll get
$$x+y=1.$$

Does it follow from the original system? Of course, it does. Is it equivalent to the original system? Definitely, **NOT**: the original system has a unique solution, while the new equation alone has infinitely many solutions (pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy it). You would need to put it together with one of the original equations (for example, as in the substitution method) to solve the original system completely.

Comment: Thank you! The confusion is less obvious when you have two variables, because you'd have to go back to the system at some point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Multiply each congruence by the inverse mod. $8$ of the coefficient of $k$, and check if the answers are compatible.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. Do you mean that the answers are not compatible? Can you elaborate a little bit please?
What is puzzling me a lot, is that nothing seems wrong about substracting the two equations. It seems correct at first, but the result is obviously not.

Comment: I didn't say they're incompatible, but they *might* be, so you have to check.  Why isn't $k$ even coherent?

Answer (score 0):

You only get a *necessary* condition for $k$ being a solution.

Suppose you have
\begin{cases}
3x=2 \\
7x=2
\end{cases}
If you subtract, you get $4x=0$, which implies $x=0$. Does this mean $x=0$ is a solution? Of course not, because $1$ satisfies neither equation. What you can say is “if $x$ is a solution, then $x=0$”.

But if you multiply the first equation by $2$ and subtract from the second, you find $x=-2$. So “if $x$ is a solution, then $x=-2$”, which is obviously a contradiction with the previous finding. Assuming a solution exists leads to a contradiction, so the system has no solution.

In your case you could indeed multiply the first congruence by $2$ and subtract from the second, getting
$$
k\equiv -2\pmod{8}
$$
Is this a solution? Let's check: if $k\equiv-2$, then
$$
3k\equiv-6\equiv2
\qquad
7k\equiv-14\equiv2
\qquad
\pmod{8}
$$
Hurray! The solution is good! Then $k=8q-2$ (or, equivalently, $k=8q+6$) are all the integer solutions.

In a different fashion, you can note that $3\cdot3\equiv1\pmod{8}$, so the first equation is equivalent to
$$
3\cdot3k\equiv3\cdot2\pmod{8}
$$
that is,
$$
k\equiv6\pmod{8}
$$
Since $-7\equiv1\pmod{8}$, the second equation is equivalent to
$$
-7k\equiv-2\pmod{8}
$$
that is,
$$
k\equiv-2\equiv6\pmod{8}
$$
Thus the two equations are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to see that, since "$2 \bmod 8$" is even and both $3$ and $7$ are not, thus $k$ must be even. So, say, we can find $m$ with $k=2m$.

Then we can [divide through](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/473827/206402) to find:
$3m\equiv 1 \bmod 4$
$7m\equiv 1 \bmod 4$

...which are of course the same equivalence, giving $m\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and so $k\equiv 6 \bmod 8$ (which solves as $k=8q+6$ for any $q\in \Bbb Z$ as stated).